# How do I pick multiple files C# UWP?

Tags: c#

I'm building a music app and need to allow the user to pick multiple files. I've tried the FileOpenPicker with PickMultipleFilesAsync() and it crashes with unexpected error.

Browsed the C# documentation with no success.

```
var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync(); // <- crashes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it filetypefilter and try again

```
openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv"); //add the type of of file you are going to select for example ".csv"
```

Otherwise from this small snippet everything seems fine.